# skip created_at field from to rspec response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Could you please help me,

When i run rspec, i got this response.body

"{:id=>1, :email=>\"email1@example.com\", :live=>true, :is_confirmed=>false, :is_pro=>false, :user_profile=>nil, :user_settings=>nil, :subscription_end_at=>nil, :is_trialing=>nil, :created_at=>Mon, 19 Mar 2018 16:45:25 UTC +00:00, :updated_at=>Mon, 19 Mar 2018 16:45:25 UTC +00:00}"

But I want this

"{:id=>1, :email=>\"email1@example.com\", :live=>true, :is_confirmed=>false, :is_pro=>false, :user_profile=>nil, :user_settings=>nil, :subscription_end_at=>nil, :is_trialing=>nil, :created_at=>"Mon, 19 Mar 2018 16:45:25 UTC +00:00", :updated_at=>"Mon, 19 Mar 2018 16:45:25 UTC +00:00"}"

I just want to removed created_at and updated_at attribute from the response because it's give the datetime object instead of string

Comment: Can you give us more detail about how you are getting this response? Based on your post it looks like it's coming from a controller request in a test, and this is serialized json. If that's true, I'd recommend looking at a serialization library like active model serializers.

Comment: Thanks @BradJohnson for reply :) and yes it's coming from a controller request in a test

Comment: @BradJohnson i'm using swagger api